# How to access argparse key name instead of value?

Tags: python, argparse

A `callee.py` has this `Namespace` using its `argparse`:

```
parser = Namespace(action='run', action_area='park', severity='high')

In [30]: parser.action
Out[30]: 'run'
```

If you type in command line, this should be enough:

```
callee.py --run --action_area gym --severity low
```

If the call is inside another program `caller.py`, I would like to do this:

```
callee.py sth.run sth.action_area 'gym' sth.severity 'low'
```

The advantages are:
  more regulated
  easier to update if args in `callee.py` change

I wish `sth` came from `argparse` or something I do not have to code myself.

I could build `sth` like this:

```
class ParserKeys(object):
    def __init__(self, keys):
        self.keys = keys
        for key in keys:
            setattr(self, key, '--{0}'.format(key))

sth = ParserKeys(vars(parser).keys())

In [91]: sth.action
Out[91]: '--action'
```

My question is: is there a way inside `argparse` or other ways that I do not have to build a class for this?

This is only an example to explain the requirements, How to achieve this is not limited to `argparse` if feature is not available(I would assume it should).

I am sure I am not the first and last one who requires this feature. I hope I explain this clearly this time.

Comment: Err, that's not the common way to use `argparse` ...

Comment: What do you even mean by "get the name which is key action"?

Comment: @user2357112, something like `parser.action.__name__` return `action`

Comment: @wim, I agree, but this is one way for explaining

Comment: @Gang: You already have the name. You had to write out the `action` name to access the value in the first place. If you're hoping to get from the plain string `'run'` to `'action'`, you should instead change how your parser is set up.

Comment: @user2357112, all I wanted is the string `action` from `parser`, not from the value `run`.

Comment: and how do you know it is the string `action` that you're after?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, `parser` is defined in one program with defined keys, while other program try to insert those args with proper keys, I want to ensure the key name is valid, `parser` does has attribute `action`, why not provide the key name in string, there must be a way!

Comment: "parser is defined in one program with defined keys, while other program try to insert those args with proper keys" - okay, you have gotten really, really confused as to how argparse is supposed to work.

Comment: @user2357112, I am not confused at how `argparse` works at all, not a single bit, I just want something extra from it or from somewhere else.

Comment: Your choice of variable names may be confusing us.  Usually `parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()`, and `args = parser.parse_args()`.  One is the parser, the other the Namespace object produced by parsing.

Comment: Since [`argparse.Namespace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/argparse.py#L1200) is a class, perhaps you can derived you own specialized version that will allow you to do what you want.

Comment: @martineau, `Namespace2(argparse.Namespace)` with `parser.x` is `--x` added? It might work!

Comment: Exactly (except you might want to try to come up with a better class name `;-)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way to use `argparse` is to define a parser, populate its 'arguments', and call `parse_args()` to parse the command line.

`parse_args()` returns a Namespace object which you then use.

It is possible to define a Namespace object directly:

```
In [203]: ns = argparse.Namespace(x=12, y='abc')
In [204]: ns
Out[204]: Namespace(x=12, y='abc')
In [205]: ns.x
Out[205]: 12
In [207]: ns.z = [1,2,3]
In [208]: ns
Out[208]: Namespace(x=12, y='abc', z=[1, 2, 3])
```

You can add values to the existing object, but you can't access values that aren't defined. The `Namespace` class is simple, just adding a few methods to make display of the values prettier.

You can also get a dictionary from it:

```
In [209]: vars(ns)
Out[209]: {'x': 12, 'y': 'abc', 'z': [1, 2, 3]}

In [210]: list(vars(ns).keys())
Out[210]: ['z', 'y', 'x']
```

Fetching a value using a `key` string:

```
In [212]: getattr(ns,'x')
Out[212]: 12
```

You can also set attributes by name

```
In [220]: setattr(ns,'w','other')
In [221]: ns
Out[221]: Namespace(w='other', x=12, y='abc', z=[1, 2, 3])
```

The method that `ns` uses to display its values is:

```
def __repr__(self):
    type_name = type(self).__name__
    arg_strings = []
    for arg in self._get_args():
        arg_strings.append(repr(arg))
    for name, value in self._get_kwargs():
        arg_strings.append('%s=%r' % (name, value))
    return '%s(%s)' % (type_name, ', '.join(arg_strings))

def _get_kwargs(self):
    return sorted(self.__dict__.items())
```

`self.__dict__` is the same thing `vars(ns)` gives. The attributes are stored in this dictionary (as is true for most objects, especially user defined ones).

If you want to do more with `Namespace`, or define your own class, I'd suggest looking at the class in the `argparse.py` file.   `argparse` tries to make minimal assumptions about the nature of this class.  Where possible it uses the `getattr` and `setattr` functions.  And `hasattr` as well:

```
In [222]: hasattr(ns, 'foo')
Out[222]: False
In [223]: hasattr(ns, 'w')
Out[223]: True
```

---

From you edits it sounds like you want to 'recover' the option flag from the attribute names in the Namespace.  That is

```
 parser.add_argument('--foo', '-f', ...)
 parser.add_argument('bar', ...)
 parser.add_argument('--other', dest='baz',...)
```

will produce a `Namespace(foo=..., bar=....)`

The attribute name is called the `dest`.  That is when saving values the parser uses

```
 setattr(namespace, dest, value)
```

For a positional argument the `dest` is the 1st parameter, 'bar' in the above example.  For an optional argument, `dest` is derived from the first long parameter, the '--foo' above.  Or it may be set with an explicit `dest='baz'` parameter.

So simply adding a `--` to the `ns.__dict__` key is a start.

There isn't any code in `argparse` that can recreate a commandline from the parsing results.

Comment: so there is no easy way to get the name of the key unless changing `argparse`, but it is possible to build a class `ParserKeys` dynamic using `vars(parser).keys() where `ParserKeys.x` is `x'?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the 'name of the key'.  `ns` has attributes, whose values have been set by the parser.  I showed how to get the names of those attributes, and how to use them to fetch values.  I'll repeat, this is a SIMPLE class object.  Nothing fancy.

Comment: Your edits are still confusing, but I'm guessing that you are trying to recreate the command line from the values in the Namespace.  That is, map a `Namespace(foo='one', bar=2)` on to `['--foo', 'one', '--bar', '2']` list.